# python: update setuptools miserable error

Tags: python

I'm trying the update setuptools by typing:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

in terminal and I got following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1431, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/_markerlib/__init__.py'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/me/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Anyone has any clues. BTW, I'm using mac if it matters.
Thanks

Comment: `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools` ?

Comment: You may have heard this a million times, but you probably shouldn't modify the system python (see macports or homebrew).

Comment: Instead of modifying system python use something like "virtualenv" or use sudo as @falsetru says

Comment: More information about virtualenv: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/